# Ingress routing rules to access prometheus server

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-ingress

I have deployed prometheus server(2.13.1) on kubernetes(1.17.3), I am able to access it on `http://my.prom.com:9090`

But i want to access it on `http://my.prom.com:9090/prometheus` so i added following ingress rules but its not 
working

**First Try:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /prometheus
  name: approot
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.prom.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: prometheus-svc
          servicePort: 9090
        path: /
```

This results in 404 error

**Second Try:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.prom.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: prometheus-svc
          servicePort: 9090
        path: /prometheus(/|$)(.*)
```

Now when i access URL `http://my.prom.com:9090/prometheus` in browser it get changed to `http://my.prom.com:9090/graph` and show 404 error

Comment: how did you install prometheus..using cores prometheus operator?

Comment: No, i installed it with manifest which is generated from helm chart

Comment: Please, can you try exposing as [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/f26f02d6) and post the result?

Comment: @mWatney it get changed to http://my.prom.com:9090/graph and throw 404 error

Comment: You have to tell prometheus to accept traffic on the new path. Please, take a look [here](https://www.robustperception.io/external-urls-and-path-prefixes) and [here](http://elatov.github.io/2020/02/nginx-ingress-with-alertmanager-and-prometheus/). Highlight to the second link, you have to include `- "--web.route-prefix=/"` and `- "--web.external-url=http://my.prom.com:9090/prometheus"` in your prometheus deployment.

Comment: @mWatney Thanks, its working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prometheus is not aware of what you are trying to achieve and that's why it's redirecting to unknown destination.

You have to tell prometheus to accept traffic on the new path as can be seen [here](https://www.robustperception.io/external-urls-and-path-prefixes) and [here](http://elatov.github.io/2020/02/nginx-ingress-with-alertmanager-and-prometheus/).

Highlight to the second link, you have to include `- "--web.route-prefix=/"` and `- "--web.external-url=http://my.prom.com:9090/prometheus"` in your prometheus deployment.

> Then I had to modify the  **prometheus**  deployment to accept traffic
>   on the new  *path*  (**/prom**). This was covered in the  [Securing
>   Prometheus API and UI Endpoints Using Basic
>   Auth](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/basic-auth/#nginx-configuration)
>   documentation:

In your env it should look like this:

```
> grep web deploy.yaml 
            - "--web.enable-lifecycle"
            - "--web.route-prefix=/"
            - "--web.external-url=http://my.prom.com:9090/prometheus"
```

Comment: I am seeing what appears to be the same problem while deploying via the prometheus-community helm chart. I added the `baseURL` and `pefixURL` attributes to my values.yaml which translates to these `--web.external-url` and `--web.route-prefix` args but when I do that, my readiness probe fails and the pod never appears as ready. When I leave the `baseURL` and `prefixURL` values out, the readiness probe succeeds but I get a 404 when browsing to `https://mycluster/prometheus`

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this issue while deploying Prometheus via the community Helm chart and figured it may be helpful to share my findings with others here: https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus

My override values.yaml looks like this:

```yaml
  server:
    prefixURL: /
    baseURL: https://my-cluster-external-hostname/prometheus
    ingress:
      enabled: true
      ingressClassName: nginx
      annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$2"
      path: "/prometheus(/|$)(.*)"
      hosts:
        - my-cluster-external-hostname
      tls:
        - secretName: cluster-tls-secret
          hosts:
            - my-cluster-external-hostname
    service:
      servicePort: 9090
```

Now the resulting deployment spec for `prometheus-server` ends up with these args (note the order and specifically that `--web.route-prefix` is at the top):

```yaml
      --web.route-prefix=/
      --storage.tsdb.retention.time=15d
      --config.file=/etc/config/prometheus.yml
      --storage.tsdb.path=/data
      --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries
      --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles
      --web.enable-lifecycle
      --web.external-url=https://my-cluster-external-hostname/prometheus
```

This does NOT work as the /-/healthy endpoint results in a 404 (from `kubectl describe pod prometheus-server`):

```
  Warning  Unhealthy  9s (x9 over 49s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
  Warning  Unhealthy  9s (x3 over 39s)  kubelet            Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
```

After much trial and error, I realized the order of those arguments seemed to matter so I changed my Helm chart values.yaml as follows:

```yaml
  server:
    # prefixURL: /   # <-- commented out
    # baseURL: https://my-cluster-external-hostname/prometheus  # <-- commented out
    extraFlags:  # <-- added this section to specify my args manually
      - web.enable-lifecycle
      - web.route-prefix=/
      - web.external-url=https://my-cluster-external-hostname/prometheus
    ingress:
      enabled: true
      ingressClassName: nginx
      annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$2"
      path: "/prometheus(/|$)(.*)"
      hosts:
        - my-cluster-external-hostname
      tls:
        - secretName: cluster-tls-secret
          hosts:
            - my-cluster-external-hostname
    service:
      servicePort: 9090
```

The resulting deployment from this values.yaml puts the arguments in the apparently proper order which makes the health check endpoint available (internally) and allows accessing Prometheus from outside the cluster. Notice where `--web.route-prefix` is located now.

```yaml
      --storage.tsdb.retention.time=15d
      --config.file=/etc/config/prometheus.yml
      --storage.tsdb.path=/data
      --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries
      --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles
      --web.enable-lifecycle
      --web.route-prefix=/
      --web.external-url=https://my-cluster-external-hostname/prometheus
```

I also submitted a bug to the community Prometheus chart:
https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/1594

Answer (score 1):

add in deploy-prometheus.yml

```
args:
    - --web.enable-lifecycle
    - --web.route-prefix=/
    - --web.external-url=https://localhost:9090/prometheus/
```

In VirtualService the Prometheus

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: prometheus-vs
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - prometheus-gateway
  http:
    - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: /prometheus/
      rewrite:
        uri: /
      route:
      - destination:
          host: prometheus
          port:
            number: 9090
```